# getting wamp to work

Tags: php, wamp

I installed WAMP on my computer and clicked start all services.

Then I tried going to http://localhost/ on my computer and nothing happened. the web page that comes up is blank. Can someone help me get this started?

Comment: and how is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that alle your serviuce are green?One of the main reason for wich wamp fails to start is that something is blocking port 80: Skype is usually the cause.

To disable skype using the port 80 just go to option->advanced->network untick the "use port 80...."

Then restart the services

Answer (score 1):

1 What WAMP do you use?
2 Check your Apache config file (httpd.conf) and search (CTRL+F) for ServerName. You should see something like `<ip>:<port>`. Is your port 80? If not, change it to 80. And if you also search for Listen there should also be something like `<ip>:<port>`, make sure that port is also  set to :80.

Answer (score 1):

goto wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\config
(probably you have another version than 2.2.17)
open httpd:

goto the line:
Listen 80

change the port to something free. (i use 99).